# Visual Studio : Linking User Control and Form

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2015, dashboard

I have created dashboard consisting of two windows -  home screen (the Form) and data screen (the User Control).
My home screen is the dashboard and upon clicking on "data" button present on the dashboard, the user is sent to the data screen (where he enters his details) . The way I'm doing this transition between the 2 windows is by making the data screen visible and bringing it to front when data button is pressed.

Q1. Is this the right way to go about switching windows? Is there a better method to do this?

Coming to the main question, the dashboard indicates whether the user has entered data or not and if yes, the user data is displayed. The code to fetch the user data is written in the user control. Now I wish to send this data to the home screen (form) so that the data can be displayed on the dashboard.

Q2. How to link the user control and form - variables wise? How to establish a Bidirectional Communication between form and user control i.e. User control should be able to read form's variables and form should be able to read user control's variables

Comment: Generically, in the **Constructor** of the UserControl, make it receive a reference to the Form. In the UserControl, declare a variable of type matching your main form and set it in the UserControl constructor.  Now the UserControl has a reference to the main Form.  The main form already has a reference to the usercontrol since it is, well, the main form (assuming the main form houses the usercontrol somehow).  If you're creating the UserControl at design-time, then the constructor approach won't work. Instead, use a property to receive the main form and set it in the Load() event of the form.

Comment: I created an object of my user control in the main form and now I'm able to access user control's variables in the main form. But how to access the form's variables in the user control? i.e. how to access parent class variables in the child

Comment: With regard to Question 1, that's completely up to you.  Only you can decide what works best for your application.  We'd need a lot more information before we could suggest other approaches...

Comment: Information like? I'm developing a GUI for a hardware project I've built. Data is sent to the GUI via serial port. The GUI simply has to fetch the data, segregate it and display it in the desired places. There is a main page on the GUI (form) and on this page are various buttons. As user clicks these buttons, he is directed to different pages (user controls)

Comment: Do the buttons stay visible the whole time?...and only the UserControls get swapped out?

Comment: If you only want ONE UserControl visible at a time, then what you're doing is perfectly fine.  If you want more than one UserControl visible at a time, then consider using a TabControl and displaying your UserControls in there.

Comment: Yup, I want only one user control at a time. I'm switching between multiple user controls as and when buttons are pressed on the main page i.e. the form. This method of hiding and showing doesn't seem elegant . I was thinking that there may be better ways to transition between user controls

Comment: Only the user controls get swapped. User control screen completely covers the main page. There is a back button on every user control to go back to the main page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two approaches...

---

### Tightly Coupled

In UserControlA, I've declared a property of type Form1 (the parent form):

```
public partial class UserControlA : UserControl
{

    public UserControlA()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private Form1 f1;
    public Form1 F1
    {
        get { return f1; }
        set { f1 = value; }
    }

    private void foo()
    {
        if (f1 != null)
        {
            // ... do something with "f1" ...
        }
    }

}
```

Then, in Form1, I set that property in the Load() event:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        userControlA1.F1 = this;
    }

}
```

This is tightly coupled because now UserControlA has a hard-coded reference to Form1.  This makes it work well with Form1, but is now less flexible as it won't work well with any other forms. If you wanted this approach to work with Form2, for instance, then you'd have to change the hard-coded type in the UserControl.

Use this approach if there is a very strong relationship between the form and the usercontrol and it's likely that the usercontrol will not be used with any other forms, or in any other scenarios.

---

### Loosely Coupled

In UserControlB, I've declared an event (BroadcastName) that will communicate a string to the outside world:

```
public partial class UserControlB : UserControl
{

    public delegate void dlgBroadcastName(UserControlB source, string name);
    public event dlgBroadcastName BroadcastName;

    public UserControlB()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (BroadcastName != null)
        {
            BroadcastName(this, textBox1.Text);
        }
    }

}
```

Now, in the Load() event of Form1 (or using the lightning bolt icon in the properties pane), we wire up that BroadcastName event:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        userControlB1.BroadcastName += UserControlB1_BroadcastName;
    }

    private void UserControlB1_BroadcastName(UserControlB source, string name)
    {
        // ... do something to Form1 with the received information in here ...
    }

}
```

This is loosely coupled because UserControlB has no idea who it is communicating with.  It simply raises its event and whoever has subscribed gets notified.  Note that this UserControl can be used with any form, without change.  This is generally a more flexible approach and makes sense when your usercontrol is more generic in nature and will be used in a wider variety of situations.

Comment: If I create an object in the form, can I access that object in user control?

Comment: Do you want to access it directly, with a **reference**, or do you want to access it "by name" via a string (searching through the forms `Controls`()` collection for a match)? For the former, create an additional "setter" method like in the tightly coupled example, and pass the reference. In the UserControl you can store that reference in a member field like in my example, or you could possibly store it in some kind of list.  For the latter approach, use [Controls.Find()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find?view=netframework-4.8).